# How to run AWS Step Functions Synchronously using the REST API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

At the moment, there isn't a way to run the StartSyncExecution Step Function method through the REST API Gateway, only through the HTTP API Gateway.

What's a possible work-around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create both an HTTP API and a REST API.

1. You setup the HTTP API that calls the StartSyncExecution on your Step Function.
2. Setup a Resource and Method that uses the HTTP integration in the REST API.
3. You put the URL for your HTTP API in to the HTTP integration of the REST API.

If you're sending data to the Step Function, make sure you use POST on both your HTTP API and REST API and set everything to passthrough (it should be by default).

Comment: I do have the same requirement, Waiting for AWS to release this